# how do I concatenate a regex in a bash alias?

Tags: bash

I can't for the life of me how to create an alias that will switch to a given project directory.

I keep all my projects in a folder called Projects i.e. `~/Project/blog` `~/Project/whatever`

I'd like to have an alias along the lines of `p whatever` that would equate to `cd ~/Project/$1` where `$1` is whatever is given to `p`.

I have tried various combinations of `alias p="cd ~/Projects/\$1"` with all the usual suspects for regex escaping but I can't quite get it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use positional arguments in aliases. Use a function instead.

```
p() {
  cd ~/Projects/"$1"
}
```

Comment: Totally works, but of course it won't autocomplete the project name. I'm guessing because it's a function and doesn't know about the underlying directory structure? Is there a way to make it autocomplete?

Comment: You'd have to use bash's programmable completion feature. See the **Programmable Completion** subsection of the **READLINE** section of the `bash(1)` man page.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you were looking for:
[how to expand aliases inline in bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/247770/how-to-expand-aliases-inline-in-bash)

so a simple solution would be using the shell-expand-line command

Define the alias without \$1

```
 $bash>alias p="cd ~/Projects/"
 $bash>p
```

just press <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> to expand getting  :

```
$bash>cd /home/USERNAME/Projects/
```

This solution puts an awkward *blank space* at the end of the expansion that you'll have to remove with <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> before writing *whatever else*.
As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams suggested a more elegant solution wolud be using a function with autocomplete properties (looking at /etc/bash_completion)