# how to expand aliases inline in bash?

Tags: bash, alias, expansion

Is there a way to expand aliases inline in bash?

```
$bash>alias ll='ls -l '
$bash>ll<tab>
$bash>ls -l
```

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> to perform the readline function `shell-expand-line` which will do alias, history and word expansions. Note that on some keyboards <kbd>Meta</kbd> is not <kbd>Alt</kbd>. You might need to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>

The functions `alias-expand-line` and `history-and-alias-expand-line` are not bound by default, but you can bind them by adding lines similar to the following to your `~/.inputrc` file.

```
"\e\C-l": alias-expand-line
```

which would make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbd> (lower case "ell") perform *only* alias expansion.

Comment: Can we map alias expansion to <tab> without affecting other bash completions?.

Comment: @asdfg: If you do, it will break other completions. It *might* work (untested) to create the map as shown above and then add this additional map to replace the existing one for Tab: `"\C-i": "\e\C-l\e\e"` which creates a macro that performs both `alias-expand-line` and `complete`. It depends on the binding from my answer above and that the default binding for Esc-Esc remains in place. You would still be able to do Esc-Esc if you wanted to do default completion.

Comment: Indeed, `ESC C-e` works for Bash, but `C-x a` works for Zsh. Also tested on OS X.

Comment: If you're simply looking for Ctrl+something, where something can be the "x" key, you can do it like this in some systems: `Control-x: history-and-alias-expand-line`.

Comment: Note that when you manually expand aliases that contain quotes (such as an `alias foo='this "bar"'`), the quotes will disappear upon expansion with Ctrl+Alt+E. But rest assured that they get properly sent to the actual command when you *really* use the alias. You can verify this by putting a `--something` option inside double quotes. The command will work when used as an alias. But your program will fail with a message such as "invalid option --something" when manually expanded to the non-quoted version.

Comment: `Ctrl-Alt-l` locked my X session ... I would suggest using other combinations.

Comment: @WeijunZhou: That depends on your window manager and any custom settings you have. For Gnome, for example, lock screen is Super+L.

Comment: @Blaz I can't get `C-x a` to work in macOS Catalina 10.15.2.

Comment: It's worth adding this works only if the alias is the first part of your line, and won't work for alias in the middle of the command, e.g. it works for ``k get po`` but not for ``watch k get po`` where ``alias k=kubectl``.

Comment: @Meitham: zsh supports suffix and "global" (meaning replaced anywhere on the line) aliases as well (with `alias -s` and `alias -g` respectively), but bash does not do those. http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_8.html

Comment: I was hoping the tab key could be overloaded so I don't have to remember another shortcut. It looks like it can't elegantly be done: https://brbsix.github.io/2015/11/23/perform-tab-completion-for-aliases-in-bash/

Answer (score 14):

For people having zsh & Oh My ZSH installed looking for a simple solution, [globalias](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/globalias) might be your friend

> Expands all glob expressions, subcommands and aliases (including global).

```
# .zsrc:
alias S="sudo systemctl"

$ S<space>
# expands to:
$ sudo systemctl
```

to install just add "globalias" to you .zshrc plugin list

```
plugins=(... globalias)
```

> Then just press `SPACE` to trigger the expansion of a command you've written.
>
> If you only want to insert a space without expanding the command line, press `CTRL+SPACE`

Comment: are you using oh-my-zsh?

Comment: That's right Should've probably mentioned it 

Comment: Haha I totally forgot about `ctrl-space` 

Comment: By the way [MichaelAquilina/zsh-you-should-use](https://github.com/MichaelAquilina/zsh-you-should-use) is the opposite. They also work together 

Comment: With Zplug: zplug "plugins/globalias", from:oh-my-zsh

Comment: @nvd isn't that the plugin I'm linking to in my answer?

Comment: @CanRau Yes, it is. I just added a comment if someone wanted to use it with Zplug.

Comment: Uuuh right, get it, didn't pay enough attention to the zplug part^^ thanks for clarifying 

Comment: Is it possible to easily toggle `globalias` on/off?

Answer (score 0):

This does not work. But I'm guessing/hoping something like this can be done to do what you want to do.
You would have to use your own completion script.
This is how you make one:

```
_ll()
{
     COMPREPLY=(ls -l)
     #The next line does not work. I just hope there were a way to replace that word
     COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]="ls -l"
}
complete -F _ll ll
```

Now source the full bash_completion file(http://caliban.org/bash) and put the above mentioned script in a file inside bash_completion.d directory that the script you get from the url references.
Let me know if it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

This actually might be a much simpler way to do what you're trying to (`bash`version >= 4.2.29):

```
shopt -s direxpand
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

`shopt`'s `man` page: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html

Comment: This is wrong. Shell options "direxpand" and "expand_aliases" do not help expand the aliases inline like the question specifies. I do not know from which hat "direxpand" was taken...? By default, "expand_aliases" is already set. If you unset it, the result is to basically disable aliases from working (they are not expanded before interpretation of the command line). E.g. given an alias  `alias ll='ls -l` the shell would interpret 'll' as command/function 'll' which likely does not exist.

Comment: @FooF: yeah, that option does something else: "Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the `expand_aliases` shell option is set using `shopt`." https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html#Aliases