# How to expand aliases inline in zsh?

Tags: macos, zsh

Similar to [how to expand aliases inline in bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/247770/how-to-expand-aliases-inline-in-bash)

I'm using zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0) and Terminal 2.10 (433).

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>ALT</kbd> - <kbd>E</kbd> works for bash, what's the equivalent for zsh?

(If `Use Option as Meta key` is disabled in Terminal use <kbd>ESC</kbd> - <kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>E</kbd>)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>X</kbd> - <kbd>A</kbd> is suggested but I can't make it work.

Comment: `globalias` plugin for Oh My ZSH might be interesting https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/globalias at least that's what I use

Comment: And if you want to reveal automatically what's behind before running the command can use this: https://dev.to/equiman/reveal-the-command-behind-an-alias-with-zsh-4d96

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just press `C-x a`, not `C-x-a` (`C-x` is a prefix).
It will call `_expand_alias` function to expand the alias.

Moreover, you can add this line to your zshrc then you can expand alias just with <kbd>TAB</kbd>:

```bsh
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand_alias _complete _ignored
```

A full example zshrc:

```bsh
autoload -Uz compinit; compinit;
bindkey "^Xa" _expand_alias
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand_alias _complete _ignored
zstyle ':completion:*' regular true
```

Comment: I actually did try `C-x a` I typed it wrong in my description, the result is only a system bell. Also the line in zshrc doesn't do anything, for example `alias pi="ssh root@10.0.1.2"` results in this when using TAB: `pi           piconv       pidpersec.d  pip          pip3         
pic          piconv5.18   ping         pip2         pip3.7       
pico         piconv5.28   ping6        pip2.7       pis          `

Comment: @eethirteenzz I have updated to answer. If still doesn't work. Check if `_expand_alias` function is defined and `bindkey '^Xa'` gives the right output.

Comment: Cheers! I was expecting zsh alias expansion to work like bash without extras, is it standard on other systems? Also, what does `autoload -Uz compinit; compinit;` actually do? Together with `bindkey "^Xa" _expand_alias` I'm set.

Comment: 1. Yes. In fact, `autoload -Uz compinit; compinit;` should be enough, it will automatically binds `_expand_alias` to `C-x a`(`bindkey "^Xa" _expand_alias`). 2. It loads and calls `compinit` function to initialize zsh's completion system, including making some keybindings.

Comment: You cannot have anything after the alias when you press `c-x a`.

Comment: Note also your cursor needs to be immediately after the alias . It doesn't expand the whole line, just the alias word in focus (just like regular tab completion, I'm new to non-tab completion so this was not obvious to me)

Comment: Also note you can see the existing completion rules by typing `zstyle` and pressing `<Enter>`

Comment: I needed both `autoload -Uz compinit; compinit;` and `zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand_alias _complete _ignored` for alias expansion to work.

Comment: How about adding small explanation for other three lines in the last code block? Anyway thank you for concise answer!