How to use abbreviations in bash prompt
Can abbreviations (like the ones in fish or vim) be used/implemented/configured in bash?
By abbreviations i mean something similar to alias but it's exanpded directly in the prompt so that I can modify the fully expanded command before pressing 

You can press Ctrl+Alt+e (shell-expand-line) to expand any alias in your current line. It can be rebound in your ~/.inputrc: https://superuser.com/questions/247770/how-to-expand-aliases-inline-in-bash
